# How to change Kivy dropdown width

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a kivy dropdown menu and I can't get the width of the button to change.  Does anyone know how to do this? I attached a photo of what the button looks like.

Here is the line where i add buttons:

```
self.drop_down.add_widget(Button(text=address, auto_width=False, size_hint=(None,None), height=self.height/15, width=self.width/2))
```

In the kv file dropdown class is empty but i have played around with various layouts to try to change the width but nothing i try works.
[image]

Changing the values for width seem to only change the label width where the text will move around on the button but the button itself wont change. The Widget is suppose to size itself to the parent width but that is not happening either. I found the value attach_to where my understanding is that i can specify what parent widget to hook to. Yet that didnt seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal **dropdown** list is different from a **actiondropdown** list and you modify the width in different ways. The way stated above is for a **dropdown** where you use *auto_width* set to *False* and then set width. But with an **actiondropdown** you use *dropdown_width* to modify the width.